# Loopback remote auth com mongodb

Tags: loopback

Tenho 2 servidores rodando com `loopback`, um deles sendo para autenticação usando `mongo-connector` e outro como um serviço secundário usando o `remote-connector` para acessar as models: `AccessToken`, `ACL`, `RoleMapping`, `Role` e `User` do servidor de autenticação.
Este esquema atualmente não está funcionando muito bem, apesar de se conectar e trazer os dados normalmente, o servidor cliente não está populando corretamente os dados da propriedade principals do access-context.
Quando faço o mesmo utilizando um memory-connector por exemplo, o mesmo funciona normalmente.

[EDIT]

Resolvido utilizando:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-component-remote-auth

Comment: Jovem, este é o stack em português, traduz sua pergunta pra que ela possa ser respondida.

Comment: Não entendi o que é que você está perguntando. E seja o que for, me parece ser algo que não tem como ser respondido sem você colocar na sua pergunta bastante informações e códigos referentes a configuração do seu sistema.